# In Azure Devops can I query the child of child work items and publish them on a board?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can I query the child-of-child work items and publish them on a dashboard?

For example in the below structure, how can I query all the user stories for an Epic?

```
Epic

 |_Feature1

      |_User Story1

      |_User Story2

 |_Feature2

      |_User Story1
```

Comment: Hi Pradipta, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your Query should be like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Successfully on my side:

[image]